# How to achieve parallel operation in Sequential Oracle design?

Tags: multithreading, oracle, oracle11g, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

we are working on a sequentially designed oracle application and we need to achieve parallel processing for that design.

Explination : We will get data into our external table from files and from there data will be moved into physical table for furthur processing. In this processing we have used some packages,triggers etc. which will process sequentially and moves the data into respective physical tables. So the problem is file has to wait for the previous file to complete fully. We have to deal with multiple users so it was a bottleneck for our situation.

Is there any way to achieve parallel processing so that multiple files can be processed at a shot?

Comment: Why can't you schedule jobs to run, one per file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved this requirement using GTT Tables. GTT tables are session independent tables , All session can run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a BULK COLLECT with parallel option to retrieve the records.
And a FORALL statement to process the records.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS01205